# Create groupPolicyDefinitionValue for new policy in Intune configuration policies using the Microsoft Graph

Tags: graph, endpoint, intune

I am following the example here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-grouppolicy-grouppolicydefinitionvalue-create?view=graph-rest-beta to create groupPolicyDefinitionValue using the Microsoft Graph.

I have already successfully used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-grouppolicy-grouppolicyconfiguration-create?view=graph-rest-beta to create groupPolicyConfiguration. However when I now try and create groupPolicyDefinitionValue I get a

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "{\r\n  \"_version\": 3,\r\n  \"Message\": \"An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer 
support):
```

So i tried it on the Graph Explorer using:

Method = POST

URL = `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/groupPolicyConfigurations/<my policy GUID>/definitionvalues/`

Body = (per document)

{
"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.groupPolicyDefinitionValue",
"enabled": true,
"configurationType": "preference"
}

and I still get:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "{  \"_version\": 3,  \"Message\": \"An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: 4200746a-36b7-82f1-b267-5fd2d22a8652 - Url: https://fef.msud01.manage.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/GroupPolicyAdminService/b15c97ad-ffff-9997-0356-041202451824/deviceManagement/groupPolicyConfigurations%28%2797381d7e-15f0-40ab-9d48-b41a09366468%27%29/definitionValues?api-version=5018-11-06\",  \"CustomApiErrorPhrase\": \"\",  \"RetryAfter\": null,  \"ErrorSourceService\": \"\",  \"HttpHeaders\": \"{}\"}",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-04-12T07:48:12",
            "request-id": "dc6daddd-f59a-4b65-b34a-b3129b59cba5",
            "client-request-id": "4200746a-36b7-82f1-b267-5fd2d22a8652"
        }
    }
}
```

I must be missing something simple. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a odata.bind to the definition:

```
{
"@odata.type":  "#microsoft.graph.groupPolicyDefinitionValue",
"enabled":  true,
"configurationType":  "policy",
"definition@odata.bind":      "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/groupPolicyDefinitions(\u002783dfbad5-0dd5-4d70-b7d0-483d1cdd40cb\u0027)"
}
```